# How to tell access that date is a week/year

Tags: sql, date, ms-access

How do I tell an access query that the date I have in the cells are weeks/year? ex. 5/2015 is week 5 in 2015.

I have tried `format([TheDate]; "ww/yyyy")` but it then converts 5/2015 to the first week of may in 2015 (20/2015)

It is only a problem with weeks below 12, as they will pass rightfully through when it is week 13-52, as there are only 12 months :P

Comment: This is not a valid format of date

Comment: A date and a week are two different things.

Comment: Can you think of a work around?

Comment: Split the String based on the **/** operator, anything before the / is the week and anything after / is the year?

Comment: I did that already. Then tried to do a Cstr(Date) split it, and add spaces on " - " But it still recognize it as a month/year....

Comment: I did a "--" instead of "-", which ruined the date format, so that worked. (It was only a problem when i put it into a graph).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have tried format([TheDate]; "ww/yyyy") but it then converts 5/2015
>   to the first week of may in 2015 (20/2015)

The reason this is happening is that you are passing a date into the `Format()` function. The date you are passing in is `5/2015` which Access believes is May of 2015 (probably May 1st). The format function then formats that date to your specified format of `"ww/yyyy"` which is, correctly, 20/2015.

This is just Access being Access. Making assumptions about your data instead of throwing an error or making you define things implicitly.

There may be ways to do this in a formula. Really ugly ways. Instead you could solve it with a UDF:

```
Function Week2Date(weekyear As String) As Date
    Dim arrWeekYear As Variant
    Dim dateJan1 As Date
    Dim Sub1 As Boolean

    'Split the incoming weekyear by "/" to an array
    arrWeekYear = Split(weekyear, "/")

    'determine the first of the year
    dateJan1 = DateSerial(arrWeekYear(1), 1, 1)

    'Add the weeks to the date and dance a little jig
    Sub1 = (Format(dateJan1, "ww", vbUseSystem, vbUseSystem) = 1)
    Week2Date = DateAdd("ww", arrWeekYear(0) + Sub1, dateJan1)
    Week2Date = Week2Date - Weekday(Week2Date) + 7


End Function
```

This will take the text date format you have "ww/yyyy" and convert it into an actual date. Since you have to make some assumptions to convert a 7 day period into a single date, this should get you close but you might have to tweak it a bit to get the exact date you want out of it (Like... perhaps you only want to start counting at the first full week and then use the Monday of each week as the date returned).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I understand the procedure and i belive it will work. However, I found a solution where I just move it into a string that can not be recognized as a date, and then added an index column. That worked fine for the purpose, since the actual week is not really important, only the order of it. Your suggestions are good since i can keep it as a date. Thank you, i might get to use it in a similar context.

Comment: I'm glad to hear you found a solution! That makes sense since you are just looking for sorting so all you need is a quick parse and you are good to go.

Answer (score 1):

You will need first a function that resolves the week-year to a date of that week. This is not that easy, as some weeks cross calendar year boundaries, and VBA doesn't calculate week 53 correctly for some years:

```
Public Function ISO_DateOfWeek( _
    ByVal intYear As Integer, _
    ByVal bytWeek As Byte, _
    Optional ByVal bytWeekday As Byte = vbMonday) _
    As Date

' Calculates date of requested weekday in a week of
' a year according to ISO 8601:1988 standard.
'
' Notes:  Years less than 100 will be handled as
'         two-digit years of our current year frame.
'         Years less than zero returns a zero date.
'         A weeknumber of zero returns the requested
'         weekday of the week before week 1.
'
' 2000-12-17. Cactus Data ApS, Gustav Brock.

    ' The fourth of January is always included in
    ' the first week of year intYear.
    Const cbytDayOfFirstWeek  As Byte = 4
    ' Number of days in a week.
    Const cbytDaysOfWeek      As Byte = 7
    ' Month of January.
    Const cbytJanuary         As Byte = 1

    Dim datDateOfFirstWeek    As Date
    Dim intISOMonday          As Integer
    Dim intISOWeekday         As Integer
    Dim intWeekdayOffset      As Integer

    ' No specific error handling.
    On Error Resume Next

    If intYear > 0 Then
        ' Weekday of Monday.
        intISOMonday = Weekday(vbMonday, vbMonday)
        ' Date of fourth of January in year intYear.
        datDateOfFirstWeek = DateSerial(intYear, cbytJanuary, cbytDayOfFirstWeek)
        ' Weekday of fourth of January in year intYear.
        intISOWeekday = Weekday(datDateOfFirstWeek, vbMonday)
        ' Calculate offset from Monday in first week of year intYear.
        intWeekdayOffset = intISOMonday - intISOWeekday

        ' Weekday of requested weekday.
        intISOWeekday = Weekday(bytWeekday, vbMonday)
        ' Calculate offset from requested weekday in first week of year intYear.
        intWeekdayOffset = intWeekdayOffset + intISOWeekday - intISOMonday
        ' Date of requested weekday in first week of year intYear.
        datDateOfFirstWeek = DateAdd("d", intWeekdayOffset, datDateOfFirstWeek)

        ' Date of requested weekday in requested week of year intYear.
        datDateOfFirstWeek = DateAdd("ww", bytWeek - 1, datDateOfFirstWeek)
    End If

    ISO_DateOfWeek = datDateOfFirstWeek

End Function
```

then a function to format this correctly:

```
Public Function ISO_WeekYearNumber( _
    ByVal datDate As Date, _
    Optional ByRef intYear As Integer, _
    Optional ByRef bytWeek As Byte) _
    As String

' Calculates and returns year and week number for date datDate according to the ISO 8601:1988 standard.
' Optionally returns numeric year and week.
' 1998-2007, Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
' May be freely used and distributed.

    Const cbytFirstWeekOfAnyYear  As Byte = 1
    Const cbytLastWeekOfLeapYear  As Byte = 53
    Const cbytMonthJanuary        As Byte = 1
    Const cbytMonthDecember       As Byte = 12
    Const cstrSeparatorYearWeek   As String = "W"

    Dim bytMonth                  As Byte
    Dim bytISOThursday            As Byte
    Dim datLastDayOfYear          As Date

    intYear = Year(datDate)
    bytMonth = Month(datDate)
    bytWeek = DatePart("ww", datDate, vbMonday, vbFirstFourDays)

    If bytWeek = cbytLastWeekOfLeapYear Then
        bytISOThursday = Weekday(vbThursday, vbMonday)
        datLastDayOfYear = DateSerial(intYear, cbytMonthDecember, 31)
        If Weekday(datLastDayOfYear, vbMonday) >= bytISOThursday Then
            ' OK, week count of 53 is caused by leap year.
        Else
            ' Correct for Access97/2000+ bug.
            bytWeek = cbytFirstWeekOfAnyYear
        End If
    End If

    ' Adjust year where week number belongs to next or previous year.
    If bytMonth = cbytMonthJanuary Then
        If bytWeek >= cbytLastWeekOfLeapYear - 1 Then
            ' This is an early date of January belonging to the last week of the previous year.
            intYear = intYear - 1
        End If
    ElseIf bytMonth = cbytMonthDecember Then
        If bytWeek = cbytFirstWeekOfAnyYear Then
            ' This is a late date of December belonging to the first week of the next year.
            intYear = intYear + 1
        End If
    End If

    ISO_WeekYearNumber = CStr(intYear) & cstrSeparatorYearWeek & Format(bytWeek, "00")

End Function
```

Of course, you can modify the last function to provide the desired string.

Comment: My reply to JNevill applies to you, too :)